# Gitlab CICD stuck on mvn help:evaluate

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have company provdied Gitlab instance where we are provided shared runners to run CICD pipleline.

I am buidling a Java project where I am looking to extract the version nummber of my applicatiion from its pom.xml so that I can amend it by suffix something like COMMIT_SHORT_SHA etc to generate a unique version no

Below is the short snippet of my .yml file.

```
before_script:
    - echo "This place is to override the version no by including Commit SHA [$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA] as suffix..."
    - echo "The maven parameter is [$MAVEN_OPTS]"
    - mvn clean
    - VERSION=$(mvn --non-recursive help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout)
    - echo "The application version is [$VERSION]"
```

The gitlab CICD pipeline just get stuck on the statement "VERSION=$(mvn --non-recursive help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout)" and then after some 9 minutes script time out and job get failed.

I tried below varitions of command but same behaviour. pipeline just stuck on command and timeout

```
mvn --non-recursive help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout

mvn -q -Dexec.executable=echo -Dexec.args='${project.version}' --non-recursive exec:exec
 
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:3.2.0:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout

mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:3.1.0:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout
```

See a screenshot showing build job log where it is stuck at three dots ...
[image]

All these 4 commands works absolutely fine when I ran in gitbash on my desktop in project root directory

Any clue why Gitlab is not able to move past this command? What is keeping it waiting?

Answer (score 1):

I would remove the -q option, and use -X instead:

```
mvn --non-recursive help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -X -DforceStdout
```

That way, you will have more logs to pinpoint why that command is stuck.

---

If the Maven command continues to hang, consider using an alternative approach to extract the version number. For example, using `grep` and `awk` on `pom.xml` file:

```yaml
- VERSION=$(grep "<version>" pom.xml | awk -F'[><]' '{print $3}')
- echo "The application version is [$VERSION]"
```

This is very much a workaround, but could help.